# How to reuse a Bokeh App with different data on an embedded Bokeh Server

Tags: python, bokeh

I've integrated the simple Bokeh app example taken from [flask_embed.html](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/0.12.5/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_embed.py) in the [Embedding Bokeh Server as a Library](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library) section of the user guide into my flask application just to verify I can properly setup the Server infrastructure needed to integrate into my flask app and that I can successfully route to it with nothing getting in the way.

What I'm not seeing clearly is how to move away from the hard association between the bokeh application and the reliance on the `modify_doc` global function which uses canned data and whose signature must be a single argument that is the bokeh document. I want to instead **push data from my model into a function that Bokeh will then render a document with**. There's a caveat that may or may not matter but the model is only populated by the user at runtime when they load a csv file that is maintained by the Flask app and the Flask session.

As a minimal example my flask app maintains a model instance which has a pandas DataFrame in it and I wish to create a Bokeh application that I can **reuse** to do a scatter plot of different pairs of columns of the dataframe. The pairs are presented to the user via links created by Flask that currently point to pages with static images generated via matplotlib. These images are created by a function that takes the pair of column names used to generate the file name and the x and y coordinates as the columns of the dataframe. The column names are passed as parameters to the flask routes which trickle down to the template that fetches the appropriate image.

Basically I want to reuse the same plotting logic upon different data in Bokeh in some functional way like I did with Matplotlib. It seems like the `FunctionHandler` technique is fixed on a data source as I've tried to create a class that maintains state that implements a `modify_doc` method but the trouble comes with the `self` parameter needed in classes.

```
class BokehParamPlot() :
    def __init__( self , paramName , x , y ) :   
        # Initialize member data
        self.paramName = paramName
        self.x         = x
        self.y         = y

    def modify_doc( self , doc ) :
        x = self.x
        y = self.y

        source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))

        plot = figure()
        plot.line('x', 'y', source=source)
        doc.add_root(column(slider, plot))
```

The spirit of the above attempt was to try to parameterize upon the `FunctionHandler` technique since the app is going to be identical just with different data and I don't want to make an app for every pair of data in my dataframe. No luck however

```
  File "ParamPlot.py", line 362, in <module>
    bokeh_app = Application(FunctionHandler(BokehParamPlot.modify_doc))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\application\handlers\function.py", line 11, in __init__
    _check_callback(func, ('doc',))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\util\callback_manager.py", line 32, in _check_callback
    raise ValueError(error_msg % (", ".join(fargs), formatted_args))
ValueError: Callback functions must have signature func(doc), got func(self, doc)
```

Looking at the Bokeh source code another promising route is the [CodeHandler](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.5/bokeh/application/handlers/code.py) but I'm hoping what I'm attempting is not some far out use case that I'm just missing some point or some connection to Base Python or something that could shortly get me on my way.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed possible by passing a query string to the bokeh app. There's a key issue to discover in this reuse scenario and that is the role of the `session_id` parameter of `autoload_server` [EDIT NOTE: this session_id functionality is only applicable to Bokeh 12.4, 12.5 broke this technique]. That session ID must be distinct between the various document renderings for different data passed through it since if you use the same ID the first data that's rendered it will be cached for the rest of the data when attempted to be rendered. If one needs to pass more parameter information through to the document you can insert to the `src` attribute of the `script` tag that's returned by `autoload_server` much like show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44401208/1330381).

The next thing is the means to make the model data visible to the module where the bokeh document is being rendered. In my case I re-layered my Flask app to store my user session models in a lower level module accessible to both the flask app main script and the plotting module where I held all the plotting logic. In my Flask home page I conduct the following logic to setup the session information in the flask session cookies and pass the a parameter from flask down to my bokeh document...

**MyFlaskApp.py**

```
@flaskApp.route( '/' , methods=['GET', 'POST'] )
def index():
    # Create or load model instance for this user session based on model uuid cookie
    if sKeyModel in session :
        if session[ sKeyModel ] not in SessionInfo.userModels :
            logger.debug( "Loading Model instance for current user" )
            SessionInfo.userModels[ session[ sKeyModel ] ] = Model( ) # TODO create new for now, but latter must support loading from persisted JSON model file
    else :
        logger.debug( "Creating Model instance for current user" )
        session[ sKeyModel ] = str( uuid.uuid1() )
        SessionInfo.userModels[ session[ sKeyModel ] ] = Model( )

    model = SessionInfo.userModels[ session[ sKeyModel ] ]
...
@flaskApp.route( '/Plots/<param>' , methods=['GET'] )
def interactivePlotsPage( param ) :     
    script = autoload_server( model      = None ,
                              session_id = "%s.%s" % ( session[sKeyModel] , param ),
                              url        = 'http://localhost:5006/' )

    return render_template( "plotsPage.html" , script=script )
```

**SessionInfo.py**

```
bokehSession = "bokeh-session-id"
userModels = {} # GUID to user Model instances maintained in the Server
```

**Plots.py**

```
def modify_doc(doc) :
    args       = doc.session_context.request.arguments
    session_Id = str( args[SessionInfo.bokehSession][0].decode('utf-8') ).split(".")
    sessionId  = session_Id[0]
    param      = session_Id[1]

    logger.debug( "modify_doc %s" % param )

    model = SessionInfo.userModels[sessionId]
    # User now has access to the model and param to drill into the model to pull out arbitrary data to conduct plots with.
```

For my application it was fine for the Flask app to maintain all the model data in memory since this was just an in house data analysis dashboard tool we used to analyze some machine learning outliers and performance with.

With the query string we can pass the arguments down to be accessible in Bokeh and you then just basically need to have access to the data you need to render in the bokeh document. There's an entry ([Bokeh Server + Flask : Passing data to plot from Flask to the Bokeh server app](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/bokeh/lk6um1OAnnI/WRlA7ox5BQAJ)) in the user group that discusses this exact situation...

> Poking around the different sources of information, I also found this
>   from Bryan Van de Ven :
>
> > There are plenty of ways to do that, and also do the "heavy lifting"
> >     elsewhere. You just need to communicate the results/data/whatever the
> >     app needs in order to do its plotting, the the app. But that could be
> >     done any number of ways:
> >
> > - apps can access HTML request args (new feature)
> > - apps can access cookies
> > - apps can access data in external databases (redis, mongo, etc.)
> > - apps can make AJAX calls to REST APIs
> > - ...
>
> Based on it, I think a possible solution could be : Generate the data
>   to be plotted (on Flask side) Obtain a session with pull_session()
>   Temporarily store the data in redis using the session.id as a key
>   Fetch the data from redis using the session_id in the bokeh app

I think the thing that really jogs your thinking is how to answer the question "how can I make the data visible to this function from a global scope?" So naturally lower level global user session data comes to mind, databases, the 
server's file system, module level state information where the document apps live, etc.

I think the gap with the flask_embed.py example is that point about how to communicate parameter info to the bokeh document left too many of these puzzle pieces a good distance from each other that made it a bit bewildering to imagine how it all works together. Thankfully I got my parameterized doc working exactly how I needed and we're flying high in Bokeh land and generally impressed with our dashboard thus far.

Comment: a much more matured version of the solution can be seen here https://github.com/jxramos/DataApp--ParamCompare