# Passing arguments to Bokeh autoload_server from Flask api

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I started using Bokeh last week, so very much new to it, I am trying to create an interactive bar chart using sliders and dropdowns embedded in Flask API, so I created the flask api for the same, its showing the chart with a slider and dropdown but its not dynamically updating the chart upon changing the slider/dropdown value.

Then upon further research I found out that I need to have a separate bokeh server running for the interaction part and call the autoload server from my Flask api. But in that I am not sure how to send my http post params to the bokeh server as my input data is from an external API with params as user input.

```
script=autoload_server(model=None,app_path="/bokeh-sliders",url="http://localhost:5006")
return render_template('hello.html',script=script)
```

In reference to [Sending URL parameter from Flask to a Bokeh server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42488003/sending-url-parameter-from-flask-to-a-bokeh-server) as I am not able to comment in it, it seems the feature has been integrated to pass arguments to the autoload server but I cant seem to find any documentation on it. Please help me in figuring this out.

On a side note, just to be sure, is it not possible to do interactions such as slider, dropdown, etc in just the flask api without running a bokeh server.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problems, not being able to add interactions with Flask, and went down the same road. 
[The issue of passing arguments is also discussed here.](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5992)

The functionality has been added to Bokeh 0.12.7, and you can now pass a dictionary of key/values to include to the app script using the `arguments` parameter:

```
script = server_document("https://example.com/myapp",
                         arguments={'foo': 'bar'})
```

Note that `server_document` is a recently-added, simpler replacement for `autoload_server`

---

For versions before 0.12.7, you can also use the following workaround (credit goes to kevinsa5 on github):

```
@app.route('/amped')
def amped():
    script = autoload_server(model = None, app_path="/amped")
    # `script` is a string that looks like this (the first character is a newline):
    """
<script
    src="http://localhost:5006/amped/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=6b813263-05df-45a5-bd91-e25c5e53c020"
    id="6b813263-05df-45a5-bd91-e25c5e53c020"
    data-bokeh-model-id=""
    data-bokeh-doc-id=""
></script>
"""
    # so to add on the necessary parameters, we have to insert them manually.  hopefully we won't need to urlencode anything.
    # note that request.args = a MultiDict, so be careful of duplicate params
    # http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict

    script_list = script.split("\n")
    script_list[2] = script_list[2][:-1]
    for key in request.args:
        script_list[2] = script_list[2] + "&{}={}".format(key, request.args[key])
    script_list[2] = script_list[2] + '"'
    script = "\n".join(script_list)
    return render_template("amped.html", script = script)
```

This allows you to access it using

```
doc.session_context.request.arguments
```

Comment: cool, thanks I will try this. Also is it possible to have multiple bokeh api's (I dont know what else to say), meaning right now I am running the bokeh server using bokeh-sliders.py in which code for only one chart is present. But I want to have multiple flask api's calling different charts, so can i make several charts in that bokeh-slider.py file and call respective chart, or is there some other way